# React Native iOS build failed at AppCenter

Tags: ios, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

Our React Native iOS project has been working well with AppCenter build. But when we pushed certain changes, although it still works well locally, the build at AppCenter failed with a weird message

```
fatal error: module 'yoga' in AST file '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/13415P9B5780C/yoga-3FGLCEI7OHU77.pcm' (imported by AST file '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...-fyxzontolgdinkbrtgzjhrtkdanv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/.../PrecompiledHeaders/...-Bridging-Header-swift_35RXECGWIBVYJ-clang_13415P9B5780C.pch') is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load '/Users/runner/work/1/s/.../ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap'?
```

After spending a long time we figured out the reason was that in our native iOS module we added categories to an Objective C class (extensions to a Swift class also will cause the same error).

Also, if we added a class method we got the same error.

Is there a way to fix these weird limitations?

Answer (score 1):

```
My RN build is also failing after archive success, I am unable to understand the root cause.

Following is the log of it.

`** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

[command]/usr/bin/security cms -D -i /Users/runner/work/1/output/build/archive/merchant.xcarchive/Products/Applications/merchant.app/embedded.mobileprovision
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppIDName</key>
    <string>My APP NAME</string>
    <key>ApplicationIdentifierPrefix</key>
    <array>
    <string>TEAM_ID</string>
    </array>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2022-01-31T07:28:54Z</date>
    <key>Platform</key>
    <array>
            <string>iOS</string>
    </array>
    <key>IsXcodeManaged</key>
    <false/>
    <key>DeveloperCertificates</key>
    <array>
        <data>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</data>
    </array>

    <key>DER-Encoded-Profile</key>
    <data...>
                                                        
            <key>PPQCheck</key>
    <true/>

    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
                
                <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
                
                <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAM_ID.com.company.merchant</string>
                
                <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
                <string>TEAM_ID.*</string>
                <string>com.apple.token</string>
        </array>
                
                <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
                
                <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAM_ID</string>
        
    </dict>
    <key>ExpirationDate</key>
    <date>2023-01-31T06:27:17Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Merchant_Adhoc_310122</string>
    <key>TeamIdentifier</key>
    <array>
        <string>TEAM_ID</string>
    </array>
    <key>TeamName</key>
    <string>XXXXX COMPANY_NAME XXXXX</string>
    <key>TimeToLive</key>
    <integer>364</integer>
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>37826bb1-0686-4364-b966-fc8633b7f2d3</string>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print ProvisionsAllDevices _xcodetasktmp.plist
Print: Entry, "ProvisionsAllDevices", Does Not Exist
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print Entitlements:get-task-allow _xcodetasktmp.plist
false
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print ProvisionedDevices _xcodetasktmp.plist
Array {
    00008101-000E68663EF8001E
    00008020-001431513C45002E
    00008030-001A35E02EF0802E
    00008030-0012343C2101802E
    00008101-000B79643603001E
    00008101-000319541468001E
}
[command]/bin/rm -f _xcodetasktmp.plist
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Clear _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
Unrecognized Type: 
File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
Initializing Plist...
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Add method string ad-hoc _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
[command]/usr/bin/security cms -D -i /Users/runner/work/1/output/build/archive/merchant.xcarchive/Products/Applications/merchant.app/embedded.mobileprovision
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppIDName</key>
    <string>My App Name</string>
    <key>ApplicationIdentifierPrefix</key>
    <array>
    <string>TEAM_ID</string>
    </array>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2022-01-31T07:28:54Z</date>
    <key>Platform</key>
    <array>
            <string>iOS</string>
    </array>
    <key>IsXcodeManaged</key>
    <false/>
    <key>DeveloperCertificates</key>
    <array>
        <data>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</data>
    </array>

    <key>DER-Encoded-Profile</key>
    <data>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</data>
                                                        
            <key>PPQCheck</key>
    <true/>

    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
                
                <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
                
                <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAM_ID.com.company.merchant</string>
                
                <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
                <string>TEAM_ID.*</string>
                <string>com.apple.token</string>
        </array>
                
                <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
                
                <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAM_ID</string>
        
    </dict>
    <key>ExpirationDate</key>
    <date>2023-01-31T06:27:17Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Merchant_Adhoc_310122</string>
    <key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
    <array>
        <string>00008101-000E68663EF8001E</string>
        <string>00008020-001431513C45002E</string>
        <string>00008030-001A35E02EF0802E</string>
        <string>00008030-0012343C2101802E</string>
        <string>00008101-000B79643603001E</string>
        <string>00008101-000319541468001E</string>
    </array>
    <key>TeamIdentifier</key>
    <array>
        <string>TEAM_ID</string>
    </array>
    <key>TeamName</key>
    <string>XXXXXXX COMPANY NAME XXXXXXX</string>
    <key>TimeToLive</key>
    <integer>364</integer>
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>37826bb1-0686-4364-b966-fc8633b7f2d3</string>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print Entitlements:com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment _xcodetasktmp.plist
Print: Entry, "Entitlements:com.apple.developer.icloud-container-environment", Does Not Exist
[command]/bin/rm -f _xcodetasktmp.plist
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Add signingStyle string manual _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Add provisioningProfiles dict _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
[command]/usr/bin/security cms -D -i /Users/runner/work/1/output/build/archive/app_merchant.xcarchive/Products/Applications/app_merchant.app/embedded.mobileprovision
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppIDName</key>
    <string>App Name</string>
    <key>ApplicationIdentifierPrefix</key>
    <array>
    <string>TEAM_ID</string>
    </array>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2022-01-31T07:28:54Z</date>
    <key>Platform</key>
    <array>
            <string>iOS</string>
    </array>
    <key>IsXcodeManaged</key>
    <false/>
    <key>DeveloperCertificates</key>
    <array>
        <data>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</data>
    </array>

    <key>DER-Encoded-Profile</key>
    <data>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</data>
                                                        
            <key>PPQCheck</key>
    <true/>

    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
                
                <key>aps-environment</key>
        <string>production</string>
                
                <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAM_ID.com.company.merchant</string>
                
                <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
                <string>TEAM_ID.*</string>
                <string>com.apple.token</string>
        </array>
                
                <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
                
                <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
        <string>TEAM_ID</string>
        
    </dict>
    <key>ExpirationDate</key>
    <date>2023-01-31T06:27:17Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Merchant_Adhoc_310122</string>
    <key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
    <array>
        <string>00008101-000E68663EF8001E</string>
        <string>00008020-001431513C45002E</string>
        <string>00008030-001A35E02EF0802E</string>
        <string>00008030-0012343C2101802E</string>
        <string>00008101-000B79643603001E</string>
        <string>00008101-000319541468001E</string>
    </array>
    <key>TeamIdentifier</key>
    <array>
        <string>TEAM_ID</string>
    </array>
    <key>TeamName</key>
    <string>XXXX MY COMPANY NAME XXXX</string>
    <key>TimeToLive</key>
    <integer>364</integer>
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>37826bb1-0686-4364-b966-fc8633b7f2d3</string>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print Name _xcodetasktmp.plist
Merchant_Adhoc_310122
[command]/bin/rm -f _xcodetasktmp.plist
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print CFBundleIdentifier /Users/runner/work/1/output/build/archive/merchant.xcarchive/Products/Applications/merchant.app/Info.plist
com.company.merchant
[command]/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Add provisioningProfiles:com.company.merchant string Merchant_Adhoc_310122 _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
[command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /Users/runner/work/1/output/build/archive/merchant.xcarchive -exportPath /Users/runner/work/1/output/build/export/_XcodeTaskExport_merchant -exportOptionsPlist _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
2022-04-08 07:07:14.342 xcodebuild[17294:77253] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path "/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/merchant_2022-04-08_07-07-14.341.xcdistributionlogs".
##[error]The operation was canceled.
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (signed)
##[section]Starting: Xcode build (signed)
==============================================================================
Task         : Xcode
Description  : Build, test, or archive an Xcode workspace on macOS. Optionally package an app.
Version      : 4.130.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613730)
==============================================================================
(node:19102) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:19102) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (signed)
##[section]Starting: Install Apple provisioning profile
==============================================================================
Task         : Install Apple Provisioning Profile
Description  : Install an Apple provisioning profile required to build on a macOS agent
Version      : 0.124.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : 
==============================================================================
##[warning]Deleting provisioning profile: /Users/runner/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/37826bb1-0686-4364-b966-fc8633b7f2d3.mobileprovision
(node:19110) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:19110) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:19110) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:19110) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:19110) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:19110) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:19110) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:19110) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
(node:19110) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
[command]/bin/rm -f /Users/runner/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/37826bb1-0686-4364-b966-fc8633b7f2d3.mobileprovision
##[section]Finishing: Install Apple provisioning profile
##[section]Starting: Install Apple certificate
==============================================================================
Task         : Install Apple certificate
Description  : Install an Apple certificate required to build on a macOS agent machine
Version      : 2.200.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-certificate
==============================================================================
[command]/usr/bin/security delete-keychain /Users/runner/work/_temp/ios_signing_temp.keychain
##[section]Finishing: Install Apple certificate
##[section]Starting: Checkout Merchant App@cicd to s
==============================================================================
Task         : Get sources
Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
Version      : 1.0.0
Author       : Microsoft
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
==============================================================================
Cleaning any cached credential from repository: Merchant App (ExternalGit)
##[section]Finishing: Checkout Merchant App@cicd to s
##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
Cleaning up task key
Start cleaning up orphan processes.
Terminate orphan process: pid (19132) (clang)
Terminate orphan process: pid (18388) (Python)
Terminate orphan process: pid (18387) (Python)
##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
##[section]Finishing: Build
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, we were able to spot the cause. When we use an extension (to either a class or a protocol) or a static var or a class function in the native module, the AppCenter build would fail with the above weird error. When we removed them, AppCenter build passed. Although the cause is spotted, the reason is not clear yet. Could it be command-line arguments in AppCenter's build script? We don't know. Anyways, try to remove

- extensions (Swift), categories (Objective C)
- static vars
- class functions

from the native module to avoid AppCenter build failure.